# What is i.h.ah, o.h.ah and int86?

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, bios, turbo-c++

I am trying to understand a program to get arrow keys. 
Here is the code:

```
int getkeys( )
{
       union REGS i,o;
       while(!kbhit( ));
            i.h.ah=0;
       int86(22,&i,&o);
            return(o.h.ah);
 }
```

can someone please explain me this code. It is to get arrow keys but i am not getting this code.

Comment: `i` and `o` are the input and output registers for the `int86` call. `ah` is a register. On input it contains the function code which is `0` for "Wait for Keypress and Read Character".  On output it contains the scancode read.

Comment: The spacing here is a bit misleading.  As written, it looks like the `i.h.ah=0;` is being done inside the while loop (which is not the case).  Some people put the semicolon after the while on a line by itself to help avoid this kind of confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turbo-C/C++'s `int86` function is used to make system interrupt calls to DOS and BIOS services. The `REGS` union is a way to address individual registers in the interrupt context data structure. In order to make a DOS or BIOS call you need to set up values in the registers based on the requirements of the system call you want to make. [Ralph Brown's Interrupt List](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int.htm) (RBIL) is an excellent source of DOS and BIOS system calls, their parameters and their return values. The [Turbo-C documentation](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/borland/turbo_c/Turbo_C_Reference_Guide_1987.pdf) defines `int86` this way:

> ```
> Name            int86  - general 8086 software interrupt interface
>
> Usage           int int86(int intr_num, union REGS *inregs,
>                           union REGS *outregs);
>
> Prototype in    dos.h
>
> Description     Both of these functions execute an 8086 software
>                 interrupt specified by the argument intr_num.
>
>                 Before executing the software interrupt, both functions
>                 copy register values from inregs into the registers.
>
>                 In addition, int86x copies the segregs->x.ds and
>                 segregs->x.es values into the corresponding registers
>                 before executing the software interrupt. This feature
>                 allows programs that use far pointers, or that use a
>                 large data memory model, to specify which segment is
>                 to be used during the software interrupt.
>
>                 After the software interrupt returns, both functions
>                 copy the current register values to outregs, copy the
>                 status of the system carry flag to the x.cflag field
>                 in outregs, and copy the value of the 8086 flags register
>                 to the x.flags field in outregs.  In addition, int86x
>                 restores DS, and sets the segregs->es and segregs->ds
>                 fields to the values of the corresponding segment
>                 registers.
>
>                 If the carry flag is set, it indicates that an error
>                 occurred.
>
>                 int86x allows you to invoke an 8086 software interrupt
>                 that takes a value of DS different from the default data
>                 segment, and/or that takes an argument in ES.
>
>                 Note that inregs can point to the same structure that
>                 outregs points to.
>
> Return value    int86 and int86x return the value of AX after completion
>                 of the software interrupt. If the carry flag is set
>                 (outregs->x.cflag != 0), indicating an error, these
>                 functions set _doserrno to the error code.
> ```

`int86` takes the interrupt number to call and two `REGS` union pointers. The first one contains the values that need to be set upon entry to the interrupt handler and the second is a way to retrieve the register values that are returned by the interrupt.

Turbo-C/C++'s definition of `REGS` looks similar to:

```
struct WORDREGS {
    unsigned int    ax, bx, cx, dx, si, di, cflag, flags;
};

struct BYTEREGS {
    unsigned char   al, ah, bl, bh, cl, ch, dl, dh;
};

union   REGS    {
    struct  WORDREGS x;
    struct  BYTEREGS h;
};
```

The `h` part of the union is simply a mechanism of addressing the high and low 8-bit registers of the 16-bit registers *AX*, *BX*, *CX*, and *DX* rather than through the full 16-bit register via `x`. This code:

```
i.h.ah=0;
```

simply sets the *AH* register (The top 8-bit register of *AX*) to 0 to pass into the `int86` function. This code:

```
int86(22,&i,&o);
```

Is making a call to software interrupt 22 (0x16). If you look at RBIL [`Int 0x16/AH=x00`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1754.htm) you find that it is the BIOS call for:

> ```
> KEYBOARD - GET KEYSTROKE
> AH = 00h
>
> Return:
> AH = BIOS scan code
> AL = ASCII character
> ```

You will see that this BIOS call returns the BIOS scan code of the next character pressed in *AH* and *AL* is the ASCII code.

The line:

```
return(o.h.ah);
```

returns the BIOS scan code of the character pressed from `getkeys`

**Note**: The code `while(!kbhit( ));` waits in a loop until a key press is detected. The Int 0x16/AH=0x00 call is being used to retrieve the BIOS scan code of that key press.

Comment: @SepRoland : took my header from TCC301 dos.h which is pretty much how all releases to that point defined it.

Comment: @SepRoland :  `h` was for half words lol. But `b` and `w` would have probably made more sense from a common sense usage perspective given that the structs use byte and word in their names

Comment: @SepRoland : A footnote would be that Watcom made a change. What they did was say in 16-bit code that `x` and `w` are the same and `h` was half. So the full register is `x` and `w` (word) are the same and `h` is the half. In 32-bit code they amended `x` so it was a DWORD (full register), `w` was a word and `h` the half.

Comment: So a change brought about out of necessity to deal with the 32-bit registers. Out of curiosity: Does Watcom exclude the use of 32-bit registers in 16-bit code then? (Treating `x` and `w` the same)

Comment: @SepRoland Yes, watcom excludes the use of 32-bit registers in 16-bit code, which makes for calling BIOS functions that require 32-bit registers (even in 16-bit real mode) a bit difficult. I'm pretty sure though that when writing 32-bit code with a 386 DOS Extender (ie Pharlap) calling down to real mode/v8086 mode to make a BIOS/DOS call - the data structures have `x` as dwords and `w` as words and the underlying function saves/restores 32-bit registers.

Comment: Should have probably said DOS/4G as that was what Watcom shipped with their compilers at one time (Not Pharlap). Didn't notice that brainphart until too late lol

Comment: This helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It calls BIOS interrupt 16h, function 00h, which is "Read key press".

When this interrupt call returns, AH will contain the scan code of the pressed key.

`int86` means "call interrupt". `22` is the interrupt number (16h, means hexadecimal 16).

`i` means the input register set to the interrupt. AH contains the function call number: 0 (There are other calls as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_16H)

`o` means the output register set from the interrupt. AH is specified (by BIOS) to contain the scan code of the pressed key.